# Tools or plugins for making parallelize NUnit tests in TeamCity

Tags: plugins, teamcity

i'am looking for tool which will make a parallelizing NUnit test in TeamCity! i wanna parallelize my tests (which goes near 12 hours) on some PC, not one, which plugin or tool can i use for it?!

Answer (score 0):

If you have several unit test projects, you could create one build configuration per agent which will be running the unit tests. Each build step would run a subset of the unit tests. You could then tie the builds together through [dependent builds](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Dependent+Build). Here is an example of an [open source project using it](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewLog.html?buildId=83218&buildTypeId=bt1075&tab=dependencies) (you can visually picture how many agents can be simultaneously running build steps.

[image: Example]

Comment: i've thought about this, but i will have got a fixув number of streams, and a lot of configurations, i need to share how many categories, so many streams